# What does the error msg ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS mean?

Tags: docusignapi

Looking at the envelope JSON there is only one recipient email. So this must indicate some other issue. Can someone steer me toward something in the docs that talks about it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the call you're attempting to make?

Comment: I can't get the code at the moment - it's the basic payload for creating an envelope with a single signer, a document and a couple of recipients. Does this error message have different meanings in different contexts? As a message it's pretty clear - what I can't find is what causes it. There doesn't appear to be any sort of error index in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [API Logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature to see exactly what DocuSign is receiving from your application.

If that doesn't help you solve the problem then **edit** your question to add the logger's output.

Use a tool such as [JSON Pretty print](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) to format your API request.

You'll also need to add 4 spaces per line so StackOverflow recognizes it as software/JSON for proper display.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it means the request JSON has duplicate RECIPIENTS arrays. It doesn't mean, at least in this case, there is a problem with recipient data.

And as far as a list of error codes there simply isn't one yet.

In this particular instance my code assembling the request incorrectly wrote the recipients array. A better message would be MALFOMED_JSON_REQUEST or such since that's what the problem actually was. Once I stopped looking at the recipients data I realized the problem.